# Is it possible to separately compile class code in c++ (like .h and .cpp) while only using one file?

Tags: c++, preprocessor, code-splitting

I'm trying to get the benefits of splitting without two files.  Split compilation without splitting storage.

I understand the benefits of separating .h and .cpp files, but I really dislike having the files be separate, specifically when the classes are tiny and each file could fit on the same page.

**Is there a precompiler option, or perhaps any other trick which would allow me to keep the benefits of separation, while having the text all in the same place?**  For example:

EDIT: please do not focus too much on this example.  It was meant to show off an imaginary pre-processor arg `#CPP_SPLIT`.  The actual code is unimportant, please, please ignore it.

```
// TinyClass.h
class TinyClass {
  TinyClass();
  int answerToLife();
}

// the following is a fake compiler arg
// in this example it would be totally unnecessary, 
// but many of my classes have some form of circular referencing
// and can not include all the code in the .h file
#CPP_SPLIT

TinyClass::TinyClass() {}
TinyClass::answerToLife() { return 42; }

#CPP_SPLIT_END
```

Comment: `because of circular references` Then give more adequate example. You can declare all functions as static, thus have same symbols per transaction unit, but that's bad. If you have circular references, then using header file to declare the functions and using the source file to define the functions is the proper way anyway

Comment: I'm trying to get the benefits of splitting without two files.  The question was good, it is you who assumed the worst of me.  There are good reasons to split, and logical reasons to not want extra files.

Comment: @SephReed To resolve circular dependencies there are other solutions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625799/resolve-build-errors-due-to-circular-dependency-amongst-classes

Comment: This is not a question about circular dependencies.  I know about forward declarations.  Please, can we keep discussion to the question rather than the impetus?

Comment: @SephReed _"I need a this because of circular references."_ Why are you mentioning that in your question then?

Comment: Because otherwise it would seem, just use `inline` or `put directly in the header` are solutions.  The example did me a disservice here, everyone keeps looking at it, and not the question.

Comment: @SephReed Don't edit already answered questions that way please. That's disrespectful. Ask another more clear question if the results here don't satisfy or solve your problem.

Comment: What "benefits of separation" specifically do you want, if you don't actually want the separation?

Comment: I want function separation, but not storage.  This post has some good reasons for wanting the function: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27456772/should-i-separate-cpp-and-h-file-in-c.  I don't want the storage because I don't like having two **text files** where one could do.  They are both just text, they can be in the same file, but still function separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure it's worth the effort, but you could place the contents of your .cpp file into `#ifdef`'d sections, like this:

```
#ifdef PART_ONE

[...]

#endif

#ifdef PART_TWO

[...]

#endif

#ifdef PART_THREE

[...]

#endif
```

... and then recompile the file over multiple passes, like this:

```
g++ -DPART_ONE   -opart1.o myfile.cpp
g++ -DPART_TWO   -opart2.o myfile.cpp
g++ -DPART_THREE -opart3.o myfile.cpp
g++ -o a.out part1.o part2.o part3.o
```

Comment: Though for most programs, things like class definitions that normally belong in a header file will need to be visible in more than one "part".

Answer (score 0):

You can simply put the implementation directly in the header like this:

```
// TinyClass.h
class TinyClass {
  TinyClass() {}
  int answerToLife() { return 42; }
};
```

Also `inline` might help to do what you want:

```
// TinyClass.h
class TinyClass {
  TinyClass();
  int answerToLife();
}

inline TinyClass::TinyClass() {}
inline int TinyClass::answerToLife() { return 42; }
```

Comment: Sorry, I added details.  There are reasons I'm asking this question.  I'm very aware you can put all code in a .h file, I'm trying to get the benefits of splitting without two files.

Comment: @SephReed You may use some `#ifdef` statements, but that requires that the code including your header sets the necessary macros using `#define` prior to the `#include` statement. Also `inline` definitions might solve your problem without ending up in multiple definitions.

Comment: I'll take what I can get.  I just really don't like having to rummage through so many files.

Comment: I'm trying to get the benefits of splitting without two files.  This would not get the benefits.

Comment: @SephReed With `inline` definitions you don't need to split your code into two files, you probably misunderstood my answer.

Comment: Does inline compile after all the .h files, similar to a .cpp file?

Comment: @SephReed I don't get what you mean?

Comment: Can I split compilation without splitting storage?  .cpp files compile after .h files.  I want to do that, but without having two files.  It's all just text, it's totally possible.  But maybe the feature does not exist.

Comment: All files compile in the order you present them to the compiler, regardless of them being .h or .cpp Are you looking for a way to make the compiler ignore part of a .cpp file?

Comment: @SephReed I still don't get what you mean? `.h` files aren't compiled prior to `.cpp` files or such, they are just expanded by the preprocessor as plain text when compiling the `.cpp` files. You should read a bit more about how the compilation and linking process really works.

Comment: Okay, you're right.  It is the order of presentation.  But usually that means .h first and .cpp later.  I want to start over.  Can you imagine a scenario in which you need to separate your cpp and h files or else it won't compile?  An example might be circular referencing, but anything you can imagine works.

Comment: @SephReed When something is put in to an .h file, it is usually a declaration that must be inserted in to multiple .cpp files.
So the .h file saves the need to copy paste. Why do you need the separation in your scenario? Are you getting errors about duplicate code?

Comment: It does not matter why I need the separation.  Can you imagine a situation where you would?  Please, yes or no.  We can move deeper into discussion from there, but I need to know if you can imagine any reason these two files must be separated.

Comment: @SephReed There's no situation that really requires you to separate declaration and definition, unless your buddy coders start complaining  about  utterly long compilation times if you do changes in your definitions.

Comment: @SephReed I can imagine several reasons to separate the files. But I can not imagine a single solution that would replace all those reasons without separation. So, if you are looking to eat your cake and have it too, help us out by explaining what flavor you are looking for - what are the features of file separation you want to achieve in a single file?

Comment: Thank you. I would like to have circular referencing without forward declaration.  I would also like to have the shorter compile times.  If you have an answer to the former problem, I'd asked another question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53796867/how-can-i-pass-this-to-a-constructor-without-circular-references-or-losing-ty/53796897#53796897, and you're welcome to suggest a non separate file solution.

Comment: @SephReed Well, there's at least one dead you'll have to die. With the current standard there's not really solution for that problem available. Maybe proposed [c++ modules](https://medium.com/@wrongway4you/brief-article-on-c-modules-f58287a6c64) might solve that better in future.

Answer (score 0):

Another potential solution to this appears to be the proposed c++ modules standard.  If you happen across this many years down the line, look there.